# How to create a "Link posting" system in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I'm new to drupal. What I want is to **share "links" of different sites - users can publish links**. Links can be a certain type of "content" -  I've some knowledge of working with custom content types & "Views". I'm assuming Links should be a custom content type, users can add new links from Add Content >> Links

This "Link" content type should have only two fields:

1. Text to display for the link
2. URL

In front page, I want a block that will display most recent links: the first field (text to display for the link) -  when clicked, viewer will be navigated to the 2nd field (URL)

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need a couple of modules to do that. You already mentioned Views to create the list of links.

To set up your content type, you will need the [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) module which provides a link field. You can configure it to display two fields, for link title ("My cool site") and link url ("http://www.example.com"). I think that new content types contain a body text field by default, but you can remove that.

I also recommend [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) in your case. In Drupal, a node is required to have a title, but you probably do not want to expose a title field to the user because the link field already contains a link title. Automatic Nodetitles allows you to hide the title field and populate it with another value, for instance the link title, the link url or even a combination of those two.

I hope that helps - if not, please clarify your question.